# Handling totally different user groups in Apache Shiro

Tags: java, spring, apache, shiro

I have a system with 2 totally different groups of users, Customers and SysAds. They reside in different table structures.

I'm trying to see how to set up Apache Shiro to correctly authenticate these users separately.

I'm using Spring + Struts 2 in my web app, and I've thought about just using 2 different master Shiro filters in my web.xml like so:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>authTravelAgentFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter>
    <filter-name>authAdminFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetFilterLifecycle</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>authAdminFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>authCustomerFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/main/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Is this a valid way to set up Apache Shiro, or is there a more correct way?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can give users roles and based on that roles give certain access.

For example, put the following in your ini file:

```
[roles]
main = *
admin = *
```

Here you just define two roles that have no specific permissions, but you can use them to restrict right to certain url patterns, so only logged in users with the right role access the restricted url:

```
[urls]
...
/main/** = authc, roles[main]
/admin/** = authc, roles[admin]
```

How to couple roles to users you can find more info here: https://shiro.apache.org/configuration.html#Configuration-INISections